# Refresh website cache and indexing

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, search-engine-indexing

I made changes to my website 2 weeks ago, ever since Google is not indexing and updating the cache. Last it is showing a cache of 16Jun on the landing page. All other search engines like DuckDuckGo, Yahoo, Bing,.. have already updated. I also submitted the sitemap in Google Search Console still no progress. I added a robots.txt file.
[image]

How long does it take Google to reindex all the changes ? I am losing leads because of that

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120932/how-to-push-google-to-update-data-about-what-i-recently-change-in-my-page/120942
Answer in above link says "Request Indexing" option in search console should help speed things.

Comment: okay @Kannan. well I requested reindexing today and is there any issue in my robots.txt file because all other search engines have already indexed.

Comment: You can use https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool to check your robots.txt

Comment: okay @Kannan thanks